# What is the efficient way to calculate number of divisors of N that are divisible by 2?.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For example if a number is given let say 8 then its factors are 1,2,4,8 hence total numbers of divisors which are divisible by 2 are (2,4,8) that is 3.

Comment: I'm checking if a number is a factor and is also divisible by 2 then count, but I want efficient method for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you do a similar problem? E.g. can you compute efficiently the number of all divisors of an number $N$?

Comment: This question is strongly related to a problem from HackerRank's "Math Programming Contest July '14" ([problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-jul14/challenges/sherlock-and-divisors)), which has now ended.

Answer (score 7):

Simply count the number of divisors of ${n\over 2}$. If

$$n=2^\alpha p_1^{e_1}\ldots p_n^{e_n}$$ is the prime factorization of $n$ then

$$\tau\left({n\over 2}\right)=\alpha(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\ldots (e_n+1)$$

This even agrees when $n$ is odd, i.e. $\alpha=0$.

Comment: How will do this in Programming?

Comment: You would have to tell it to find the prime factorization of $n$, a hard problem in general, but then it's equivalent to finding all the divisors, so there's no "easy" way to do it, unless you can prove GRH.

Comment: List<int> Fact2(int val)
        {
            if (val % 2 == 1) return new List<int>();

            List<int> dividors = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 1; i < val >> 1; i++)
                if (val % i == 0) dividors.Add(i<<1);

            return dividors;
        }

Comment: @Seb That is still $\mathcal{\Theta}(n)$, and thus not the efficient one can do.  And what's with the bitshifts?  (Modern compilers don't need *that* much help from the programmer for optimization)

Comment: agree @anorton numbers ranges from  1 to 10^9, so Θ(n) won't work here.

Comment: Sorry for the O(n) algorithm, I don't think "Schnorr-Seysen-Lenstra Algorithm" will be that easy to program  ;)  And for the bitshift, opportunity to use them are rare so when I can ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Do you know how to calculate the number of divisors of a number from its prime factorization?  Now you require the exponent of $2$ to be at least $1$.

Comment: no sir, I don't know how to do this please explain.

Comment: You could see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)  The line under Properties that starts $\sigma_0(n)$ is the one you want.